# Prove: for a continous $f$: $f$ has the mean value theorem on spheres $\iff$ $f$ has mean value theorem on balls

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove: for a continous $f : \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$: the mean value theorem on spheres holds for $f$ $\iff$ the mean value theorem on balls holds for $f$, wherein the mean value theorem on spheres is: $f(x_0) = \frac{1}{vol(S_{n-1})}\int_{S_{n-1}}f(x)dx$ where $S_{n-1}$ is a sphere centered at $x_0$ with a radius of $r$.

My thoughts:
The direction $\rightarrow $ holds because the average of $f$ on a ball is the weighted average of $f$ on spheres inside the ball with radius $\leq r$. The other direction seems to require a counter-example, but all I can think of are examples where the property holds for a lot of balls, but not all of them.

I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Consider the integral over a thickened sphere, i.e., the difference between two balls of almost equal radius. Use that spheres are compact.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can kind of see what you mean... I'm not sure how to use the fact that the sphere is compact. I mean the difference of the open balls is compact, so therefore it must be the sphere?

Comment: No, compactness should help you show that the integral over the thickened sphere is approximately the integral over the sphere times thickness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this in $\mathbb R^2,$ assuming we have the area mean value property at $0.$ Then for $R>0$ we have

$$f(0) = \frac{1}{\pi R^2}\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} f(re^{it})\, dt\, rdr.$$

Verify that the inner integral is a continuous function of $r.$ By the FTC, we can differentiate the above with respect to $R$ to get

$$\tag 1 0 = \frac{-2}{\pi R^3}\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} f(re^{it})\, dt\, rdr + \frac{1}{\pi R^2}R\int_0^{2\pi} f(Re^{it})\, dt.$$

The first expression on the right side of $(1)$ equals $(-2/R)f(0).$ So simplifying we get

$$f(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} f(Re^{it})\, dt$$

for $R > 0.$ This is the mean value property at $0$ for circles as desired.

In higher dimensions it's the same argument, once you have the analogue of polar coordinates there.